# Execute a function when a row from a DataGrid is pressed in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, row

I´m trying to implement a functionality over my DataGrid when one row get pressed a function executes. I´ve tried to use the DataGridCell.Selected, the problem with this one is that it executes "n" number of times for each column of the grid and i want that this method executes only one time. I also tried with DataGridRow.Selected but it doesn´t works. Any ideas of how can i do this?

EDIT: the function has to execute with just one click over the row, that´s why i´m not using MouseDoubleClick

***XAML***

```
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel  Background="#373A6B" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
        <DataGrid x:Name="ListNameTest" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" CanUserAddRows="False" 
                           GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#CBC3C3" 
                  Margin="0" Padding="-5,0,0,0" Height="400" Width="550" DataGridCell.Selected="DataGridCell_Selected"
                          IsEnabled="True" >
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary >
                    <Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridCell}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1F800C" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="uno" Binding="{Binding id}" IsReadOnly="True"  CanUserResize="False" Foreground="#FFF" FontSize="20">
                    <DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#2ECBC6"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight"  Value="Medium" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,0" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="15,0"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
```

thank you beforehand:)

Comment: You essentially need a row selection event, don't you?
This is the SelectionChanged event of the DataGrid itself.
In the event parameter, the RemovedItems property is the lines from which the selection is removed, AddedItems - which are selected.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed it. Thank you so much :)